# How to sync password in AWS Cognito and Mysql database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, mysql-python

I am using **migrate user lambda trigger** to copy existing users in MySQL to Cognito. But in the case of forget password event while migrating user (event: **UserMigration_ForgotPassword**) there I want to maintain consistency in password in our existing database and AWS Cognito database.
Is there any way I can update the password in MySQL as well after AWS Cognito reset the password?

The problem is by using UserMigration_ForgotPassword trigger password only get updated in AWS Cognito and not in MySQL database.